# Viewchild get element ref with multiple selectors

Tags: angular, viewchild

In my template, I use ngSwitch to populate a mat-select, input with matInput, mat-select etc. How can I `use @ViewChild(MatInput | MatSelect, {read: ElementRef})elementRef;`?

Comment: You can target more than one selector by separate each selector with a comma

Comment: How about `@ViewChildren` with `#identifier`?

Comment: [Here is @Eliseo's answer pictured](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5hwitc)